# How to assign a numerical value to a check RadioButton and pass this onto the next activity (similar to a questionnaire app)

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am new to Android development and I am trying to design a simple questionnaire-type app. Each question has set answers within a RadioGroup. I would like to assign a numerical value to the checked RadioButton so I can then send this to the next activity where eventually it will be used to total the scores and produce a message.

I have been able to create a toast; for testing, to show which RadioButton is checked. But I am having trouble with assigning a value to each RadioButton once checked. I know that I will need to use a IF statement but not sure how. Can anyone help or send me a link to a good tutorial?

Here's some sample code within one of my .java file;

```
public class Diabetes_Question_1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diabetes_question_1);

    Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack1);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Diabetes_Question_1.this, Diabetes_Question_2.class));

        }
    });

    final RadioGroup radioDQ1Group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioDQ1Group1);
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext1);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Diabetes_Question_1.this, Diabetes_Question_3.class));


            int selectedId = radioDQ1Group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();


            RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(Diabetes_Question_1.this, rb1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
    });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Every view has a tag-  an object that can hold whatever data you want.  Use it to hold the integer value-  you can do that via setTag() and getTag().  Then when you start the new activity, add it to the extras bundle of the intent you launch.  The new activity should then read that value from the incoming intent.